# Groovy Socket Programming and IP-Address

Tags: sockets, groovy, ip

I want to write a small groovy script.

This is my script, which is working:

```
s = new Socket("localhost", 1234);
s << "RUN"
s.close()
```

But I don't want to use the hostname (here it is 'localhost'), I want to use the IP-Adress, but if I write the following Code it doesn't work.

```
s = new Socket("xx.x.xx.xxx", 1234);
    s << "RUN"
    s.close()
```

I also tried it this way:

```
s = new Socket(new Inet4Address("xx.x.xx.xxx"), 1234);
s << "RUN"
s.close()
```

I get always a connection refused exception:

> Caught: java.net.ConnectException:
>   Connection refused: connect  at
>   web3.run(web3.groovy:1)

I know, this piece of code does not really make sense, but it is all I need.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this notation?

```
s = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("xx.x.xx.xxx"), 1234);
```

Comment: No, I haven't. But it doesn't work either. I think this is not a groovy problem, it maybe is a problem with my firewall or anything else on my computer, I haven't figured out yet. If I use 'localhost' everything is fine, if I use '127.0.0.1' it works too, but if I use my real IP address not.

Comment: make sure whatever server your connecting to is binding on the real IP. a lot of servers can be configured to listen only on bound addresses. to test this, simply try a basic telnet onto the host and port

Answer (score 0):

> Caught: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect at web3.run(web3.groovy:1)

Looks to specify that the host you are connecting to (web3.groovy:1) is down or not listening on that port?

if its a *nix system.  Try:

netstat -na | grep 1234

See if you are actually listening on that system on that port.